# Does $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ imply that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Suppose $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Does this imply that imply that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

If you only have two of these radicals, it follows easily as if $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}$ so $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}\in\mathbb{Q}$, but I can't seem to use this method for sums of three radicals.

If this is true for sums of three radicals, then it leads to an alternative proof of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R-Q}$

> Suppose $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$.Then  $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$, so $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}-(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5})=2\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ which clearly false. Hence, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R-Q}$

I am not looking for proofs of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R-Q}$ ; I am just wondering if there is a way to make this method work.

Comment: The difference between your two numbers is $2\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Yes, vacuously.  :) $\qquad$

Comment: @tilper I was trying to avoid that. Is there a better way to word it in order to assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is true?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about rephrasing it as based on everything on this page it should be clear to anyone who'd be able to help you what it is you're looking for.

Comment: What method? Havingt wasted 5 minutes on an answer that I now realise you will think is irrelevant, I am voting to close. When you say "this method", you appear to mean "a method along these lines that I can't articulate"? To anyone reading your question, there is a much more obvious method; the sum of quadratic surds cannot be rational, so your assumption is counter-factual.

Comment: @RobArthan I added what my method of proof I to my question.

Comment: What you have added is a valid proof that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \in \bbb{Q}$ implies that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5} \not\in \bbb{Q}$. It is far from clear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @RobArthan I am asking if we assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is true, does that mean $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is true. If so, then what I added would be a proof for why $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R-Q}$

Comment: If you assume a false statement, then you can prove anything. If you are looking for a more subtle analysis of the algebra here, then you need to think your question through much more carefully.

Comment: @RobArthan  Don't you have to assume a false statement in order to use proof by contradiction, which is what I am using to prove $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is not rational? I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: What you say about proof by contradiction is not quite right in the case of statements involving free variables. But the point here is that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$ contains no free variables and is false, so it is just bizarre to ask if it implies some specific statement like $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$ when it actually implies any statement whatsoever. It is completely unclear what you actually want to know.

Comment: @RobArthan so if I wanted to prove $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational, I can't assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational and follow the steps I outlined to obtain a contradiction?

Comment: That line of argument is logically acceptable, but how do you fill in the details of the first step without assuming what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @RobArthan This is where I am confused. I do not know where I am assuming $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational. I assume $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational, show this means $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-
 \sqrt{5}$ is also rational, subtract the two, obtain $2\sqrt{5}$ is ratiional, a contradiction. Where in that did I assume what I am trying to prove?

Comment: What's your proof for the first step?

Comment: @RobArthan That is the point of this question I posted. I thought Fimpellizieri showed this, but it needs $\sqrt{6}$ to be rational, so I was not thinking it through. My prof showed something that involved more advanced field theory, but that is beyond my understanding. I wanted to know if there were any proofs to my first step.

Comment: Exactly! So your question needs a major rethink by you to explain what it is that you really want to know. The only proofs on offer for your first step assume what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$, then the difference is in $\Bbb{Q}$, and that would imply that $\sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$

Comment: That does not answer my question. We do not know if $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ yet.

Comment: @EthanGodden : I propose a proof by contradiction. If both expressions are rationals numbers, then $\sqrt{5}$ is also a rational number. As $\sqrt{5}$ is not a rational number, then both expressions cannot be rationals

Answer (score 1):

One has that

$$a-\sqrt{b}=\frac{1}{a+\sqrt{b}}\cdot(a^2-b)$$

Take $a=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and $b=5$. Then

$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}\cdot(5+2\sqrt{6}-5)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}\cdot\sqrt{6}$$

So, **under the assumption that** $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}$, it is true that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}\in \mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $\sqrt{6}\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I suspect you mean $b=5$

Comment: Oops, you are right.

Comment: So what? It is even easier to see that **under the assumption that** $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$, then $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$ iff $2\sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree with you, but what of it?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: why do all that algebra to conclude something that can be seen much more directly? But ,apparently, the OP likes it $\ddot{\frown}$ even though the very first comment on the question points down the easier path.

Comment: @RobArthan The OP did ask for a specific method of solution.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: the OP did not ask for a "specific method of solution" in any sense that proscribes the simpler answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is not in $\Bbb{Q}$, so $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \in \Bbb{Q}$ implies any proposition you like.

Comment: I wanted to phrase it in a way that assumes $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is true. Is there a better way to phrase it?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your question is mis-phrased, in that you appear to be using the symbol $\mathbb{Q}$ to represent *any field* containing the given element, rather than its usual usage for 'the rationals'.  If this is true, then the answer to *the question you are really asking* would be 'yes' - the extension of a field by the root of any quadratic [such as '$x^2$-5'] is automatically a splitting field, i.e it contains both roots [because their sum is the linear coefficient of the quadratic]. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ contains $\sqrt{2}$ and -$\sqrt{2}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})$ contains $\sqrt{2}$, -$\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$ and -$\sqrt{3}$, and finally $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3})(\sqrt{5})$ contains $\sqrt{2}$, -$\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$,-$\sqrt{3}$, $\sqrt{5}$ and -$\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{Q}$ to mean the rationals. I do not know any field theory unfortunately.

Comment: @EthanGodden You seem to be thinking along the lines of "Can we use algebraic operations to get from $x = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ to $y = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3 - \sqrt5$ in such a way that $x \in \mathbb Q$ would imply $y \in \mathbb Q$?" The way to make this formal is to define the field extension $\mathbb Q(x)$ of things that you can compute using $\mathbb Q$ and $x$, and ask if it also contains $y$. In other words, field theory was invented to deal with the question you're asking rigorously!